# PyPy3 потребляет много ОЗУ(x10) по сравнению с Python3

Tags: python-3.6, pypy

Решил попробовать использовать PyPy3 вместо Python3. В результате чего потребление памяти скриптами выросло в среднем в 10 раз.
Отдельные скрипты доходили до 3ГБ. Сами скрипты не очень требовательны к ресурсам, но могут исполняться от 3 до 12 часов (основное время в ожидании задач).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой и способами её решения?

PyPy3 (Python 3.5.3 - [PyPy 7.0.0 with GCC 6.2.0 20160901] on linux)

Python3 (Python3.6.7 -  [GCC 8.2.0] on linux)

Comment: Наверное, у PyPy сборщик мусора ни разу не вызывался :D

Answer (score 1):

Ручная сборка мусора помогла с решением проблемы.

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Теперь максимальное использование памяти не превышало 400MB (это не 3GB).
Похоже, если чаще вызывать сборщик мусора, то можно ещё уменьшить размер нагрузки. Но мне достаточно и одно раза в конце основного цикла.

Всё же, при переходе на PyPy, ожидал, что там сборщик мусора как и в питоне работает автоматически.

Comment: Вот что значит пальцем в небо и попасть :)

Comment: Сборщик мусора в PyPy очень весьма отличается от дефолтного. http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/gc_info.html#fragmentation По ссылке можно прочитать чо почем про возвращение памяти в ОС и почему этого может не происходить